# Why do I see an old build when publishing with VS2019?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, iis-10, visual-studio-2019

I have a .net core 3.1 web app, using VS2019 and I'm publishing a self-contained package to IIS 10 on the production server via FTP.

The app runs fine on my local server, but when published the production server sometimes shows a previous build, while other times everything publishes correctly.

It makes me concerned every time there is an update because I don't know what I'm going to get. Not sure if this is VS doing something weird, or if it's a server cache issue?

I've tried deleting all the files from the server and then publishing again, with the same hit-miss results.

Has anyone experience this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think this may relate to the client’s browser’s cache issue.
As you said, even if we delete all old files and then publish it, we are still getting the same hit-miss results. This doesn't seem to have much to do with the server-side. In order to eliminate this factor, please try to open the browser’s privacy window to verify that the website has been updated.
Especially certain static content resulting in this issue. There are ways around this, such as renaming the static file `CSS/Js` (adding the updated version number) so that client’s Http request forces the local browser cache to be updated.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.